# open loop transfer function

Tags: control-theory, z-transform

a block diagram system is given as per the attached image.
[image]

what is the open loop transfer function?

i say it is found by opening the loop and multiplying all of the terms. So that:
U = KFYX. Then rearrange for output over input. 
HOWEVER, my friend say you just ignore the return path completely, so that U = KFY and then you rearrange for output over input.

Based on the definition for open loop TF it seems both could be correct as it is ambiguous. Can anyone tell me the correct answer with authority?

Comment: Your friend (and you) are partially wrong. $Y$ is just the output so it must not be included in the transfer function. Now, the open loop transfer function is found by "cutting off" the feedback just before the adder, so it should be $H(s) = K F X(s)$. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJOZ4dj0hnw) as well.

Comment: beautiful. thank u so much

Comment: do u have a link to a source which says so too?

Comment: Are you using a textbook? You should be able to find examples there.

Comment: I have a couple from the library and have searched online but to no avail for this particular example. I never see it asked for the open loop TF when there is already a feedback line. Only when it is actually an open loop (in the references I have searched so far). If you or anyone can recommend a source of info on this point, I would be happy :-)

Comment: Look at Section 2.3 (Figure 2-4) of Ogata's [Modern Control Engineering](https://www.amazon.com/Modern-Control-Engineering-Katsuhiko-Ogata/dp/0136156738), 5th ed. If you read closely, you will notice that that open loop transfer function is the ratio of the feedback signal to the actuator signal, so it has to be $K F X(s)$. This is a definition that should be available in any control systems textbook you pick up.

Comment: Lastly, by extension... the open loop poles and open loop zeros would be calculated from the open loop transfer function? So in this example, let K be a constant, F = 1 / s and X is also = 1 / s. In this example, there would be no open loop zeros and 2 open loop poles (both at s = 0). Is that correct?